# Workflow with Git and remote server

Tags: git, workflow, virtual-machine, development-environment, gitlab

I'm looking to improve our workflow using Git and our development servers.

We have it set up so in addition to our production and staging server, each dev generally runs their own local VM. We also keep our code in a GitLab repository.

Amongst the devs, there are two main ways we get our code on to the server:
- Push to GitLab, then pull from the local server
- Run a daemon on the local VM, then push directly to it

As you can imagine, this means we have to make many frequent commits as we are working on things. We try to work on a different branch for each feature, but it's still a bit cumbersome. I'd like us to start rebasing each branch or feature to a single commit so the log looks nice (no need to keep the intermediate steps).

However, as I understand it, once you've pushed to a remote server (like GitLab), rebasing because very difficult and impractical.

Is there a workflow where we can easily put files on our server via our repo, yet retain a means to rebase without creating lots of headaches?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it is relative to a coding tool, it is not a specific code question as requested by the faq but a general best-practice discussion.

Comment: @Seki I tried to rework the question to make it a little more specific, as I am after a specific answer to a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Squash commits" functionality when creating a Merge-Request. Squashing commits from a Merge Request means to compact all the commits in this request into only one commit.

[image]

If you don't want to use the GitLab interface for that:

```sh
# If you want to merge my-feature-branch to master
git checkout master
git merge --squash my-feature-branch
```